# mixed functional and non-functional requirement

Tags: grammaticality

**Some background:**
Functional requirement of a web service is concerned with the correctness of the web service's function, say the service will always return a number that is less than two.

The non-functional requirement of a web service is concerned with the performance of the web service, say the service will response in 5 ms.

**Question**:
The mixed functional and nonfunctional requirement is concerning both, say the service will return a number that is less than two in 5 ms.

Is "**The mixed functional and nonfunctional requirement**" grammatical?

Comment: As an aside, _within_ might be a better preposition than _in_. The word _in_ could be interpreted as _exactly_, while _within_ in this context means _in no more than_.

Comment: Incidentally, on the programs I work on we'd probably write your new "mixed" requirement something like:  *Upon receipt of a <blah-be-blah> command, the service shall return a number less than 2 within 5 milliseconds.*  <Trigger> <Expected behavior> <Constraint>

Comment: I am programmer :) You should keep it simple. **The mixed functional and nonfunctional requirement** == **The requirements**. Do not specify/define what is not need - never!. As an aside **your definitions** of functional and non-functional requirements are invalid. Functional is what user requested defined and Non-functional is programmer requiments to fulfill Functional (i.e. requirements to design database derived from Non-Functional). **Non-functional requirements** is **always** derived from **Functional**. Functional could be technical requirements! - if user express such requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nearly.

> The mixed functional and nonfunctional **requirements**

is grammatical. It's probably not what you mean though. Instead you might want to say

> Both the functional and non-functional requirements

or since "**functional and non-functional X**" is tautological, just

> All of the requirements

will do.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend "all of the requirements;" in all likelihood, there are more than just these two, and "all" could be interpreted to include more than the two being discussed.

Comment: @J.R. Even if there are several requirements, each one is either functional or it is non-functional. Hence the set of requirements formed from the set of requirements that are functional and the set of requirements that are non-functional is the total set of all requirements. It's like saying "put both the green balls and the non-green balls into the bag" <=> "put all of the balls into the bag".

Comment: Yes, but other requirements (like, "The system shall allow the user to save the results") have nothing to do with the returned number, or the 5-second response time. The O.P.'s statement is unrelated to those requirements, so "all" is not the right word to use there. In this case, the O.P. isn't asking about the complete set of functional and non-functional requirements, but one particular one from each set.

Comment: I am programmer as explained below in answer **the requirements** == **the functional and non-functional requirements**. _All of the requirements_ is not natural it is tautological too. Some joke: _I brought left and right side of bread joined together_ == is just _I brought bread_ :)

Answer (score 1):

In this context, I think the verb *combine* would read better than *mix*. It's hard to say for sure, because both words can be used in a wide variety of contexts, but I believe *combine* suggests a more orderly blending than *mix*.

Here some wordings you might consider:

> Combining these two requirements, the service shall return a number that is less than 2 within 5 ms.
>
> When these functional and non-functional requirements are combined, the service shall return a number that is less than 2 within 5 ms.

If the requirements are numbered, you could be more formal and specific:

> By combining the functional requirement 3.2.7 with the non-functional requirement 4.1.3, we see that the system must return a number less than 2 within 5 ms.

That last one is a bit wordy and legal-sounding, but such a tone is not unusual in the context of formal documentation, where ambiguity can wreak havoc on a project.

Comment: I think OP is saying that there is now a single new "mixed" requirement stipulating both a functional behavior and a time constraint and wants to know how he can label this new kind of requirement.  I might call it a "performance constrained functional requirement."

Comment: @Jim: That's a good thought; you may be right. I'm not sure if the O.P. is looking for wording help with the general case, or this specific case. (As you may have guessed, I interpreted it as the latter.) This is just one more example of why it behooves those who ask questions to provide as much context as possible; I hope the O.P. weighs in with additional clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I am programmer - Your definition functional and non-functional is totally wrong (see below explanation of etymology) - it is very common mistake. You define non-technical and technical requirements.

You should say simple (without repeats and tautology) **The requirements** == **The mixed functional and non-functional requirements** since F A set and non-F A set is always A set. Same is with *functional and non-functional* or *technical and non-technical*.

---

The **functional requirements** is what user/customer specifies (whatever it will be including technical parameters like speed of service!) - why? - user/customer defines what functions/features it **must have** == **functional**.

The non-functional requirements is what programmer specifies to fulfill user/customer/functional requirements!

For example user/customer specifies web service returning something with speed 5s is **functional**. Programmer derived from it that it requires database, some database tables, validation of data and web server in some configuration - it is **non-functional requirements** - why? - programmer defines what functions/fetaures it **should/may have** to realize functionality == **non-functional**.